# Regex capture group that excludes a group

Tags: regex

Here is the test string:

```
[x] Package - Front and Rear align, rotate and balance 4 wheels ------------------- $105.00
```

I want to capture multiple groups as follows:

- Group 1: Open square bracket, 0-3 characters then close bracket
- Group 2: Longest text that excludes --
- Group 3: Longest text that has only -
- Group 4: remainder

Here's my failed attempt

```
^(\[.{0,3}\])(.+(?!.*--.*))(-*)(.*)$
```

Also I do not have access to lookbehind if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^(\[[^][]{0,3}])\s*(.*?)\s*(--+)\s*(.*)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IYY5Nd/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\[[^][]{0,3}])` - Group 1: a `[` char, then zero to three occurrences of any chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(--+)` - Group 3: a hyphen and then one or more hyphens
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 4: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible.